# quoting string in perl while substitution

Tags: perl

I have to use the substitution method in perl.
But the problem is that the string to be replaced is fairly complex and contains special characters.

String to search:

```
K6D2wlawNtxOMrTOiEwnz12Y1qvn
```

String to replace:

```
TO_DATE('03/31/2013 02:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

While the string to search is fairly simple, the string to replace is fairly complex and normal substitution wont work:

```
perl -p -i -e "s/$search/$replace/g" file
```

Is there any other quotation method in perl wherein I can over-ride these regex rules and simply replace the above complex string?

I must stress that I CANNOT edit the string to replace as it comes from other sources, can be various other functions in SQL and hence are not in my control.

Answer (score 4):

Use another substitution delimiter, ie `s|` vs `s/`

```
perl -p -i -e "s|K6D2wlawNtxOMrTOiEwnz12Y1qvn|TO_DATE('03/31/2013 02:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')|" file
```

Comment: He doesn't know what will be the string, so he can't know for sure his delimiter of choice won't be there. This isn't acceptable, he must quote the string.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to treat it as a normal string, you should call *quotemeta* on it to escape any special characters, or use the equivalent sequences, i.e.

```
perl -p -i -e "s/\Q$search\E/\Q$replace\E/g" file
```

Comment: It worked fine with search=ruby and replace=python (when quoting didn't matter). But it didn't when search=r/u$b/y and replace=p/y/t$h/o/n. Why didn't it work?

Comment: I run this: echo $search | perl -pe "s/\Q$search\E/\Q$replace\E/g" and get this: Having no space between pattern and following word is deprecated at -e line 1. syntax error at -e line 1, near "s/\Qr/u$b/y\E/\Qp/y/t$h/o/n\"

Comment: The \Q doesn't effect the / between the pattern and replacement; it's easiest to avoid using the separator character within either, which you can do since perl allows arbitrary chars. i.e.

s:\Qr/u$b/y\E:\Qp/y/t$h/o/n: or s/{Qr/u$b/y\E}{\Qp/y/t$h/o/n}